# setting wait time on dispatch_group

Tags: swift2, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to set the wait time on a dispatch group but unless I set 'DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER', the wait time is being ignored.

If I wanted to set the wait to 5 seconds, how do I achieve that? Or do I need to change to a semaphore and put a timeout on that object?

sample code:

```
dispatch_group_enter(group)

async(handler: handler)

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

All I am after is to replace DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER with a number (e.g. 5 seconds).

That is all. Any number (for example 5, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC, Int64(number), UInt64(number)) or other permutation is being ignored by the wait.

Comment: please, put here some lines of code, what you did, what did you expect and what was done by your code :-). it can help us to understand your needs ...

Comment: OK,  " ... wait time is being ignored", means that it returns immediately?

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant. Code returns immediately.

Comment: May be every work has been finished in the group so code returns immediately??

Comment: and yes, if all work has been done, dispatch_group_wait will return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope, this example is 'self explanatory'. see, how timeout is defined!

```
import Foundation

let group = dispatch_group_create()
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    var i = 0
    while i < 15 {
        print(i)
        i++
        usleep(500000)
    }
    dispatch_group_leave(group)
}
//dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
let t = dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5000000000)
dispatch_group_wait(group, t)
print("stop")

/* prints
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
stop
*/
```

> Declaration dispatch_time_t dispatch_time( dispatch_time_t when,
>   int64_t delta); Parameters when    The dispatch_time_t value to use as
>   the basis for a new value. Pass DISPATCH_TIME_NOW to create a new time
>   value relative to now. delta   The number of nanoseconds to add to the
>   time in the when parameter. Return Value A new dispatch_time_t.
>
> Discussion The default clock is based on mach_absolute_time.

You can use simplified version with the same functionality

```
import Foundation

let group = dispatch_group_create()
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
dispatch_group_async(group, queue) { () -> Void in
    var i = 0
    while i < 15 {
        print(i)
        i++
        usleep(500000) // 0.5 sec delay
    }
}
// wait time a little bit more than 1 second
let t = dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1100000000)
dispatch_group_wait(group, t)
print("stop")

/* prints
0
1
2
stop
*/
```

with

```
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

the same code prints all 15 numbers (0...14)